# Get latest row using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

It appear I am not getting latest row when rows have actually same `created_at` value.

Using `$model->latest()->first()` - I am getting first row rather than last row of `created_at`.

How to solve this?

Comment: if the created_at is the exact same, i'm pretty sure you're going to have a hard time sorting using created_at

Comment: @Giovanni I actually want to get a last row even exact same created_at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will entirely depend on what other data you have in your table. Any query of a relational database does not take the "physical position" into account - that is, there is no such thing as being able to get the "last inserted row" of a table until you are able check some value in the table that indicates it is the *probably* the last row.

One of the common ways to do this is to have a auto-incrementing unique key in the database (often the Primary Key), and you can simply get the largest value in that set. It's not *guaranteed* to be the last row inserted, but for most applications this is usually true.

What you need is the equivalent query to be executed

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE created_at = ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

or, in Eloquent ORM

```
$model->where('created_at', '=', ?)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->first();
```

Keep in mind that you'll probably need other filters, since it is entirely possible other users or processes may insert records at the same time generating the same creation date, and you'll end up with somebody elses records.

Answer (score 3):

`latest()` will use the created_at column by default.

If all of your created_at values are the exact same, this obviously won't work...

You can pass a column name to `latest()` to tell it to sort by that column instead.

You can try:

```
$model->latest('id')->first();
```

This assumes you have an incrementing id column.